# EmberJS Search Store

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am attempting to write a small action that searches the data store, which already has data loaded into it by the way.  I would like to be able to search by a string, i.e. a firstname.

Here is an example of the code I have so far.  this.get() is grabbing the value from the search form and I know it's getting the correct value from the input field.

```
actions: {
    search: function() {
        return this.store.all('person', { firstName: this.get('firstName') });
    },
}
```

And here is the model:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:      attr('string'),
    lastName:       attr('string'),
    email:          attr('string'),
});
```

When I run this action, it simply returns ALL of the records in the DS.

Also, separate question but does Ember do LIKE statements?  Let's say the first name is Stanley and I enter in Stan.  Would it retrieve Stanley or does it look for exact matches only?

I cannot find anything via google or the documentation, and I may be phrasing the question the wrong way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`

```
var liveCollection = this.store.filter('foo', function(record){
  // if the bar property is baz include it in the collection
  return record.get('bar')=== 'baz'; 
});
```

So for your case it'd be

```
search: function() {
    var fn = this.get('firstName');
    return this.store.filter('person', function(record){
       return record.get('firstName') === fn; 
    });
},
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *find* instead of *all* function

```
return this.store.find('person', { firstName: this.get('firstName') });
```

Comment: That does an HTTP request and I don't need that.  I already have the data loaded into the store.

Answer (score 0):

To search in an already loaded store you can use [peekAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll) the get all records and then find by using the `findBy` method. This won't trigger an request.

```
return this.store.peekAll('person').findBy('firstName', this.get('firstName'));
```